# anyway to get the mic activity/level in toxbox on iOS

Tags: ios, opentok, tokbox

I'm using tokbox on iOS. I want to know which of the publishers has the loudest stream at anyone time... on js api there's a detectMicActivity function.

is there anything similar for iOS? My other option is do dummy recording, on each device and send the values of RMI; but I'd like to avoid that if there is a built in provision for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:

The OpenTok iOS SDK now supports audio level activity events for each Subscriber. You should implement the [OTSubscriberKitAudioLevelDelegate](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Protocols/OTSubscriberKitAudioLevelDelegate.html) protocol and set the [audioLevelDelegate](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Classes/OTSubscriberKit.html#//api/name/audioLevelDelegate) property of the OTSubscriberKit instance to that object.

---

The OpenTok iOS SDKs do not have an interface for getting realtime audio levels from the video streams.

With that said, I think you meant to phrase your question a bit differently. Usually there is only one Publisher, and one or more Subscribers. Publishers represent the stream from the current device (or connection) while Subscribers are all the other streams on the session.

Also, the detectMicActivity method on the Publisher for the Web is only available for the OpenTok 1.0 version of the platform (Flash). TokBox is maintaining that version but its unlikely there will be any more features coming to it. You should consider moving to 2.0+ versions (WebRTC) where newer features like the one you are asking for is planned.

Comment: I didn't meant to phrase the question differently. I was suprised to find out the stringent limits on publishers. I've since abandoned their platform for ooVoo which is miles better, and has much better performance too.